# Por qué cuando paso una tarjeta nfc me dice que no es compatible

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nfc

Quiero saber por qué cuando paso una tarjeta nfc me dice que no es compatible.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import android.nfc.FormatException;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public class NFC extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        NfcAdapter adapter;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        IntentFilter writeTagFilters[];
        boolean writeMode;
        Tag myTag;
        Context context;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //Definimos el layout a usar
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc);
            context = this;
            //Los elementos que vamos a usar en el layout
            Button btnWrite = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
            final TextView message = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
            //setOnCLickListener hará la acción que necesitamos
            btnWrite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try{
                        //Si no existe tag al que escribir, mostramos un mensaje de que no existe.
                        if(myTag == null){
                            Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.error_notag), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{
                            //Llamamos al método write que definimos más adelante donde le pasamos por
                            //parámetro el tag que hemos detectado y el mensaje a escribir.
                            write(message.getText().toString(),myTag);
                            Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.ok_write), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                }catch(IOException e){
                        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.error_write),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }catch(FormatException e){
                        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.error_write), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
            IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
            tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[]{tagDetected};
        }
        //El método write es el más importante, será el que se encargue de crear el mensaje
        //y escribirlo en nuestro tag.
        private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException{
            //Creamos un array de elementos NdefRecord. Este Objeto representa un registro del mensaje NDEF
            //Para crear el objeto NdefRecord usamos el método createRecord(String s)
            NdefRecord[] records = {createRecord(text)};
            //NdefMessage encapsula un mensaje Ndef(NFC Data Exchange Format). Estos mensajes están
            //compuestos por varios registros encapsulados por la clase NdefRecord
            NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(records);
            //Obtenemos una instancia de Ndef del Tag
            Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
            ndef.connect();
            ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
            ndef.close();
        }
        //Método createRecord será el que nos codifique el mensaje para crear un NdefRecord
        @SuppressLint("NewApi") private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
            String lang = "us";
            byte[] textBytes = text.getBytes();
            byte[] langBytes = lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
            int langLength = langBytes.length;
            int textLength = textBytes.length;
            byte[] payLoad = new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];

            payLoad[0] = (byte) langLength;

            System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payLoad, 1, langLength);
            System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payLoad, 1+langLength, textLength);

            NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], payLoad);

            return recordNFC;

        }
        //en onnewIntent manejamos el intent para encontrar el Tag
        @SuppressLint("NewApi") protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
            if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){
                myTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                Toast.makeText(this, this.getString(R.string.ok_detected) + myTag.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        public void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            WriteModeOff();
        }
        public void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            WriteModeOn();
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi") private void WriteModeOn(){
            writeMode = true;
            adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, writeTagFilters, null);
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi") private void WriteModeOff(){
            writeMode = false;
            adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: como la verifico si puedes ayudarme

Comment: osea la tarjeta la paso por el telefono pero sale tarjeta no compatible

Comment: Baja una aplicación que haga lo mismo que tú quieres para verificar si no es el formato de la tarjeta

Comment: con otra aplicacion si la reconoce

Comment: Entonces es código, he trabajado con escáners pero no con Android y lo que he tenido que hacer es por código escribir los parámetros de configuración iniciales es lo más que te puedo ayudar , esperemos que llegue un experto al caso

Comment: Las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad. Además, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Lee [ask] y  cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones para editar tu pregunta.